# Add Grand Total end of the row for each customer

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I need to get Total for each Customer

I have a table like this.

```
    Create table mytbl 
    (Branch varchar(10),
     CustCode varchar(10),
     Name varchar(10),
     Address varchar(10),
     MarketingCode varchar(10),
     CCVal varchar(10),
     Tot1 int,
     Tot2 int,
     Tot3 int)
```

**Sample data**

```
INSERT INTO mytbl (Branch,CustCode,Name,Address,MarketingCode,CCVal,Tot1,Tot2,Tot3) 
           VALUES 
           ('1','5001','MY C NAME','SA','12','10',100, 0, 0),
           ('1','5001','MY C NAME','SA','13','5',0, 300, 0),
           ('1','5001','MY C NAME','SA','15','8',50, 0, 0)
```

I need to get Sub Total for Tot1, Tot2 and Tot3 For each customer
Group by Branch,CustCode

I have written query like

```
SELECT *, 
       SUM(Tot1) As t1,
       SUM(Tot2) As t2,
       SUM(Tot3) As t3 
from  mytbl 
GROUP BY Branch,CustCode  
WITH ROLLUP
```

It shows the following error

> Column 'mytbl.Address' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT *" is the problem.

Yo must have something like this:

```
SELECT Branch,CustCode, SUM(Tot1) As t1,SUM(Tot2) As t2,SUM(Tot3) As t3 from  mytbl GROUP BY Branch,CustCode  WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: But i need to show all the columns Branch,CustCode,Name,Address,MarketingCode,CCVal

Comment: That is why I said "something like this", the original issue was the "*"

Answer (score 0):

Pls have a look [at this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#group-by-grouping-sets--) for bit more understanding on GROUP.

GROUP BY (even with GROUPING SET) clause required all the column to be included that are mentioned in SELECT clause excluding the ones inside aggregation function (in your case SUM).

Hope following is the one that you looking for, [for more examples and test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1bbf7170b8f9fa274ad7390573de4b9a):

```
SELECT   Branch, CustCode, name,
         SUM(Tot1) As t1,
         SUM(Tot2) As t2,
         SUM(Tot3) As t3 
from  mytbl 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (ROLLUP(Branch, CustCode, name))
```